# Were Grungs created for 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, grung

In *Volo's Guide to Monsters*, there is a race in the bestiary called Grungs. Were these created for 5e specifically?

I'm pretty sure they were created for 5e, as they have no deities listed which is always a bit suspicious, but I'm just making sure.

Comment: Related, representing a part of this question now removed: [Are there any official Grung deities? (the D&D frog-like Grungs)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133829/1204)

Comment: Question was originally closed down (for asking two questions). It was reposted here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133824/37067 

In the end, this question was reopened and cleaned up, and the newer one closed as a "duplicate".

Answer (score 44):

The grung are a Greyhawk-based amphibian race.  They first appeared in Greyhawk Adventures (1988), then in Monstrous Compendium Greyhawk Appendix, MC5 (1990).

Their primary deity is the Greyhawk-based demigod [Wastri, the Hopping Prophet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wastri). Here's [an Oerth Journal article](http://mcgillsociety.org/dnd/dnd-misc/codex/greyhawk/religion/wastri.htm) (fanzine) with great detail. Wastri is a demigod of human supremacy and amphibians.

"Bath Time for the Hopping Prophet" is an adventure card from the City of Greyhawk boxed set featuring a cultist of Wastri and some grung.

Comment: *Nice!* Do you happen to know if there is any relation between the **grungs** and the  **grippli** (1st ed. *Monster Manual II*)? Or are they just both batrachian humanoids?

Comment: No relation.  The grung were originally more toad type and grippli smooth skinned frog type.  And there are bullywugs too.  Like fish people and reptile people, game designers can’t have just one when three will do!

Answer (score 14):

They appear on page 27 of the *Greyhawk Adventures* supplement published by TSR in 1988. (Avalibable now on DMsguild) However, no dieties are listed for them there either.