# Were Grungs created for 5e or did they exist before this edition?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, lore

In Volo's Guide To Monsters there is a race in the bestiary called Grungs. Were these created for 5e specifically?

Comment: Does [mxyzplk's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/98122/35259) to the linked question answer your question?

Comment: The original question got closed down with the specific comment "please separate and repost the two issues", deleting some replies as not being on topic.  

So now I have. You can't both have the cake and eat it too. Either the original question was the correct place for the reply (and it should be undeleted) or the splitting I just did was the correct couse of action, and the second part (I posted as soon as the 40 minute delay expired) is where my reply can live without deletion.

Thanks.

Comment: @user37067 I can see why that was confusing, you're right that you did what was asked. However in this case what was asked was slightly misworded. What's been done now is the original question has been re-opened as the first question ("Do grungs predate 5e") so this one is a duplicate. The grung god question is now open, so hopefully you now have the two questions you need open and ready for answering! Sorry for the mix up

Comment: Closure of this question discussed on meta [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8480/23970).

Comment: lol. thx. 54321